# What am I? Beat the clues

Tags: riddle

It can be hard or soft

---

It’s closer than you think

---

The fog is clearing

---

It’s wet in there

Comment: Hi @Aimz, welcome to Puzzling SE! (Take the [tour] if you haven't already!) Did you get this riddle from an outside source other than yourself? If so, [proper attribution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is required, and the post needs to be edited to include at minimum where it came from. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is this...

> Water

It can be hard or soft

> It can either be ice (hard) or soft (water)

It’s closer than you think

> Air is partly made of water, just think about humidity

The fog is clearing

> I don’t know but fog is condensed water

It’s wet in there

> water is wet

Comment: rot13(Uneq be fbsg pbhyq nyfb or nobhg gur zvareny pbagrag bs jngre)

Comment: Closer could also be a clue to the parlance rot13("vg srryf pybfr va urer", zrnavat zhttl (be uhzvq))

Comment: @Adam you’re right